# Sharing Private Conversations

Tags: privacy

I work in HR. I’ve just had a coworker with whom I shared my frustrations (talking poorly about the company and others coworkers) regularly go and expose all my comments to upper management. I completely trusted this person, but turns out she documented everything for weeks and claims I made her feel uncomfortable. This was a two way vent session that we shared on a regular basis. I feel completely violated. Is there nothing I can do? I was not fired or written up, but now I feel uncomfortable at work now.

Comment: How you know this person went to upper management? How did you find out if you weren't even written up?

Comment: Also, how did this person supposedly documented what you said? Unless the person has some recording of you saying it then such evidence would be week... and if that person has a recording is because it's legal on your state.... that reminds me, what is your location (country)?

Comment: Were those verbal conversations?

Comment: Are you peers?  In other words, are you at the same level?  Or are you above or below her in the hierarchy?

Comment: There's a lesson here to be learned. Don't talk badly about the company. Especially if you work in HR. There's something you can do: Stop doing it, and hope everything blows over.

Comment: Deny it, admit it and try to address your problems or ignore the problem.

Comment: Privacy laws differ by state, or country. Is it a one party consent where you live? In general, there is no privacy at work and any electronic media is monitored.

Comment: Wow, where is [Linda Tripp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linda_Tripp) working now? Oh, and you should learn from your mistakes. You certainly should not broadcast it from here to the world.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there nothing I can do?

Yes there are several things you can do.  First, **do not repeat** this behavior again.  Especially with anyone at work when you are in a management or HR position.  If your conversations and such were exposed to management, consider yourself **lucky to still be employed**.

If you are approached in the future for vent sessions, **politely decline**.

*Everyone* needs to vent on occasion, this is normal human nature.  Just *don't do it* with someone you work with or via social media.  Use your non work friends or family to vent your frustrations.

Comment: Just vent to a mirror on your own.